# How to call a method that is inside an object that is imported in different file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, module.exports

Error: main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: r.sum is not a function

```
// calculator.js
let calculator = { 
    sum: function(a, b) {return a + b}
};


module.export = calculator;
_______________________

// index.js

const calculator = require('./calculator')

console.log(calculator.sum(3,4));

or

//index.test.js

const calculator = require('./calculator')
```

I need to use the object method for testing purposes.

Error: when I can to use the

```
main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: r.sum is not a function
```

Comment: where is your main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo... ;)

```
module.exports = calculator;
```